# how to force jQuery UI Dialog to redraw again or trigger something to force resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Have some issues with the Dialog Widgetm when displaying dialog, it shows as this:
[image]

But when using the mouse to resize the dialog, this issue dissapears, resizing the dialog.
Now what I want is force resizing the dialog by code.

This is the way I initialize the dialog and how I calles it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dialogAccess").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width:'auto',
                resize:'auto',
                modal: true,
                position: {
                    my: "center",
                    at: "center",
                    of: window
                },
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog('option', {
                        width: 300, height: 400, position: {
                            my: "center",
                            at: "center",
                            of: window
                        },
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        function accessQuestions(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: someUrl,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg.d == true) {
                        $("#dialogAccess").dialog("open");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

How can I trigger a resize event or force re-drawing the dialog?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this "But when using the mouse to resize the dialog, this issue dissapears, resizing the dialog". Does the dialog resize immediately to the correct size or do you have to drag it to the correct size? I'm assuming it's the former, but best to get confirmation.

Comment: I did mean that need to use the mouse to resize to any size, then the dialog resize to correct size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by css, it was modified several times, by the designers of the ui. So I downloaded the original file from the jquery.ui page and replace it. then the issue disappear.